# video playback stops while sharing the screen to apple-tv

Tags: appletv, screen-sharing

I just recently faced this problem, while I have high quality broadband bandwidth and each devices (laptop, apple-tv ,etc) can stream 1080 flawlessly, but the moment I hit the apple tv button, the online streaming (fb or youtube) stops playing back. If I cancel sharing the screen with apple-tv it resumes playing back!!

p.S: I have this problem only with online streaming, offline video playback is fine on apple-tv. Bandwidth test with apple-tv is passed without any problem.

Some info:

`laptop: mac-Pro 15" retina`

`apple-tv model: A1469`

`apple-tv software: 7.0.2(6915)`

Comment: we need to find your bottleneck, since the slowest device on your network will dictate the speed for all others.

Comment: but everything used to be the same config as before. I am using the same cable network among all devices using a 100Mb switch.

Comment: speedtest shows 80Mb down and 12Mb up in my Mac, since the switch is a simple `NETGEAR 5-ports`, i am assuming that it split the bandwidth in fair.

Comment: the bottleneck is not on your side, it is on utube or FB, check those speeds.